# Tomcat 7.0.26 failing to start jsvc

Tags: java, linux, apache, tomcat

So I had a tomcat 7.026 smoothly running on a CentOS 6.7 Server on its default port 8080. 
Recently it stopped running on its own.
Here are the out put of each:

```
sudo service easy-tomcat7 start
```

```
Failed to start Tomcat
```

sudo service easy-tomcat7 status

> pidof: invalid options on command line!
>   pidof: invalid options on command line!
>   jsvc.exec is stopped

```
ps aux | grep tomcat
```

> root      4293  1.4  2.3 5939868 389996 pts/0  Sl   14:16   0:14
>   /usr/java/jdk1.7.0_05/bin/java
>   -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/conf/logging.properties
>   -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
>   -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/share/apache-tomcat-7.0.26/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

> root     16821  0.0  0.0   8548   384 ?        Ss   14:30   0:00
>   jsvc.exec -user tomcat -cwd /usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7
>   -pidfile /var/run/easy-tomcat7.pid -cp /usr/local/easy/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/easy/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/local/easy/share/java/commons-daemon.jar
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/endorsed -outfile /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.out -errfile /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.err -verbose
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

> tomcat   16823  9.4  3.5 6190668 574344 ?      Sl   14:30   0:15
>   jsvc.exec -user tomcat -cwd /usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7
>   -pidfile /var/run/easy-tomcat7.pid -cp /usr/local/easy/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/easy/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/local/easy/share/java/commons-daemon.jar
>   -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/endorsed -outfile /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.out -errfile /var/log/easy-tomcat7/catalina.err -verbose
>   org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start

Killing those processes aren't helping , as well as service start, restart, force-reload ... etc

Finally here's the script of easy-tomcat7

```
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

case $1 in
    start)
        file=/usr/sbin/starttomcat
        # no way to start tomcat
        if [ ! -x $file ]; then
            echo "Missing $file"
            ERROR=1
        else
            # tomcat disabled by whm
            if [ -e /etc/tomcatdisable ]; then
                echo "Tomcat is disabled by cPanel/WHM"
                ERROR=0
            else
                ERROR=0

                status jsvc.exec &>/dev/null

                # tomcat already running
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    echo "Tomcat already started"
                # start tomcat, not running
                else
                    $file &>/dev/null
                    sleep 1 # just to make sure
                    status jsvc.exec &>/dev/null

                    if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                        ERROR=0
                    else
                        echo "Failed to start Tomcat"
                        ERROR=1
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        fi
        ;;
    stop)
        file=/usr/sbin/stoptomcat
        if [ ! -x $file ]; then
            echo "Missing $file"
            ERROR=1
        else
            $file
            ERROR=0
        fi
        ;;
    restart)
        file=/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_tomcat
        if [ ! -x $file ]; then
            echo "Missing $file"
            ERROR=1
        else
            $file
        fi
        ;;
    status|fullstatus)
        status jsvc.exec
        ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status|fullstatus}"
        ERROR=2 esac

exit $ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved the issue.

After running

```
java -version
```

It seemed that the Java Installation was somehow corrupted so all I had to do was to uninstall and re-install Java and that made the trick for me.